# php ltrim many characters at once

Tags: php, performance, trim

Hi is there a better and faster way to clean many characters from beginning of a string?

I have this one, but is this really the fastest way?

```
$description_new = ltrim($description_new, '###');
$description_new = ltrim($description_new, '.');
$description_new = ltrim($description_new, ',');
$description_new = ltrim($description_new, '!');
$description_new = ltrim($description_new, '?');
$description_new = ltrim($description_new, ')');
$description_new = ltrim($description_new, '(');
```

Thanks
Nik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the second parameter can be a charlist:

```
$description_new = ltrim($description_new, '#.,!?()');
```

You could also add a range of characters if it would suit your needs:

```
$clean = ltrim($binary, "\x00..\x1F");
```

Read about: [function.ltrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

Comment: Strange: I have the one string with "- Php Core-developer ..." and the function ltrim($description_new, '#.,!?()-'); not cleaned the string. Any ideas why?

Comment: @NikoNik for me it worked. Or did you mean the space? Then add a space to charlist `'#.,!?()- '`

Comment: @NikoNik ok, but remember there are many types of dashes. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)